# Compare data attribute and text fileld value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to compare text input value to data attribute value.
I select text field value from jquery auto complete selection option and I set attribute at that time as follows

```
select: function (event, ui) {
 var terms = $(this).attr('dt-value') ? $(this).attr('dt-value') + ',' +  ui.item.value.replace(',', '|,') : ui.item.value.replace(',', '|,');
 this.value = terms.replace(/\|,/g, ',');
 $(this).attr('dt-value', terms);
 return false;
}
```

But in edit option if user deletes value using backspace attribute will not updated.

```
 dt-value="NMC|, ltd,Coromandal|, LLC"
```

But in text field value shows without **|** symbol. I want to update the attribute with current value in text field if user remove one value.
Kindly help

Comment: There is **change** event available you can try that. 

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Comment: Yes, change() could be a solution. We can help you if you fill a JSFiddle or similar.